# How can I customize error message when running singleton rcp4 application second time?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

How can I customize error message when running singleton rcp4 application second time? Now the default message is:

> could not launch the product because the associated workspace is currently in use by another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LifeCycle` class `@PostContextCreate` method runs before this check is done so you can add your own code there to do the check and display your own message.

The checks done by Eclipse are fairly complex, you can see the code in the `checkInstanceLocation` method in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application` class

Comment: And how I can close my application from the LifeCycle class in @PostContextCreate method ?

Comment: Since this is early in  the startup `System.exit(0)` should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.